# Putting axis and title labels in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a line plot using R and ggplot2.  My code is

```
# sample data
list <- data.frame(day = 1:30, pct_excessive = rnorm(30, 0,1))

library(ggplot2)
 g <-ggplot(list, aes(day, pct_excessive))
 g+ geom_point() +geom_line()
 +  labs(x="day") + labs(y="percentage of excessive hold times")
 +  labs(title="October 2017")
```

I am getting the plot I want, but the labs statements and title are not working.
The console message is `Error: unexpected symbol in:
" g+ geom_point() +geom_line()
 +  labs(x="day"`

> - labs(title="October 2017 Percentage of intervals with excessive hold times")
>     Error in +labs(title = "October 2017 Percentage of intervals with excessive hold times") : 
>     invalid argument to unary operator
>     g <-ggplot(list, aes(day, pct_excessive))
>     g+ geom_point() +geom_line()
> - labs(x="day") + labs(y="percentage of excessive hold times")
>     Error in +labs(x = "day") : invalid argument to unary operator
> - labs(title="October 2017")
>     Error in +labs(title = "October 2017") : 
>     invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Rewrite your code nicely (don't put `+` on the new line).

Comment: try to move '+' to the end of last line, instead of starting a new line with '+'

Comment: @May, I'm not sure why you're being downvoted, so please ignore it. As others have shared in comments, and as I show below, your question is perfectly fine and has a straight forward answer.

Comment: @RichPauloo I didn't down-vote, however please note that the answer to the question can be found in the [**first google hit**](https://www.google.com/search?q=invalid+argument+to+unary+operator+ggplot) when searching for `"invalid argument to unary operator ggplot"`. I imagine that this explains (some of) the down-votes.

Comment: @Martius, thank you, and I understand that it's an answer that's easily googled. I just don't want new users to feel intimidated by SO. Furthermore, actually helpful answers shouldn't be downvoted. This is probably a conversation for meta, so I'll stop here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with your code, but how the code is **formatted**. In particular, you can't begin lines with `+`. The `+` should be on the preceding line. For example, this works:

```
# generate some data
list <- data.frame(day = 1:30, pct_excessive = rnorm(30, 0,1))

library(ggplot2)
g <-ggplot(list, aes(day, pct_excessive))
g + geom_point() + geom_line() +  
  labs(x="day",
       y="percentage of excessive hold times",  
       title="October 2017")
```